# TextWrap AND TextTrimming in a "flying" grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want to create a LiveTile. The text that will be displayed comes from a different backend so I don't have access or control. So I wanted to prerender the text (like this: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_Live_Tile_with_Formatted_Text).

But I wanted to go 1 step further and Wrap and Trim the string as it MIGHT become longer.
A short version of the code is:

```
var wbmp = new WriteableBitmap();
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = pWidth;
grid.Height = pHeight;

var tblk = new TextBlock();
tblk.Text = pString;
tblk.Width = pWidth; // 691 or 336
tblk.Height = pHeight; // 336
tblk.TextTrimmin = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
tblk.TextWrappin = TextWrapping.Wrap;

grid.Children.Add(tblk);

wbmp.Render(grid, null);
wbmp.Invalidate();
```

This didn't trim the string. Then I read a bit about grids and texttrimming and I already have one xaml-part that does wirk woth both Oo So I did something like this:

```
var rowDef = new RowDefinition();
rowDef.Height = GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
rowDef = new RowDefinition();
rowDef.Height = GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

tblk.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0); // or 1 // or Grid.SetRow(tblk, 1);
```

and tried different combinations of Rows and Columns, Auto, Pixel and Stars. But nothing works. As the grid is not bound to anything else, "is flying" in the void, it doesn't create multiple rows. If I copy the same text in 4 colours and put it in 4 rows it only shows the upper one, because all others are exactly underneath..

What am I missing here? It can't be impossible to Trim and Wrap at the same time Oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) methods of the `UIElement` to actually get the desired image. So here is the full code:

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = 80;
grid.Height = 80;

var tblk = new TextBlock();
tblk.Text = "Long enough text to show you text wrapping and trimming at the same time in this example.";
tblk.Width = 80; 
tblk.Height = 80; 
tblk.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
tblk.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

grid.Children.Add(tblk);

grid.Measure(new Size(80, 80));
grid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 80, 80));
grid.InvalidateVisual();

var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(80, 80, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(tblk);
```

After that you can use the `renderTargetBitmap` as a `Source` for an `Image` element, and you will see that the text is both trimmed and wrapped.

Comment: Oh boy, THANK YOU. I wasted half of yesterday to find a solution and couldn't find anything that helped. And here it's so easy... :D Thanks :)